# Connecting SQL Server (On-prem) to Powerapps

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerapps

I've created a SQL Server Express instance and setup a Data Gateway within powerapps.

The Gateway appears properly in the SQL Server dialog window, but when I add the credentials it pauses for a minute then returns a `DMTS_EncryptClusterCredentialsErrorCode` error message.

After looking at this with a Server Admin for ~1 hour we were unable to figure out what the issue is. We have TCP/IP enabled and are able to connect to the Database in question properly from our desktops, so it shouldn't be an issue with the db setup.

Anyone have experience with connecting SQL Server 2017 Express to Powerapps or know anything about this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up submitting a ticket to MS regarding this issue and after working with the rep for a while, it came down to toggling the https switch.

Hope this saves someone the hassle of going through MS support.

Comment: I am getting the same error connecting to SQL Server Express on an Azure VM (simulating something that will later be on-premise).  Where did you toggle the https switch on this?

Comment: In the "On Premise Data Gateway" setup window.