# PowerApps cannot connect to on-premise SQL Server through On-Premise Data Gateway

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, data-gateway

I'm trying to setup a data connection from PowerApps to an on-premise SQL Server instance we have. However, I get the following error:

> Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem#ports) support article from Microsoft to get it set up.

Everything I've done so far:

- The SQL Server Express instance is setup on a normal Windows 10 Pro machine we have within our domain.
- I've created a service account on the domain to access SQL Server, and added the db_owner role for it on the database we're trying to access.
- I've configured SQL Server to allow external connections with a non-standard port (49172), and tested this using another machine within the domain to connect using the service account, which works great.
- I installed the On-Premise Data Gateway from Microsoft and configured it using my work Microsoft account. That works fine as well, and I can see the gateway in PowerApps listed as Live. HTTPS is enabled (recommended on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885130/connecting-sql-server-on-prem-to-powerapps))
- I've added explicit rules allowing all the ports and whitelisted all the IPs suggested by MS in the support article I followed (link above).

The weird thing is if I change the username/password to something incorrect, it gives me an "invalid credentials" error, so I know it can at least hit the domain/SQL Server to authenticate. Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm an idiot and had the SQL Server name wrong. In the tutorial I watched the instructor just listed the computer name (which is what I was doing), but I needed to add a backslash and SQLEXPRESS as well.

- Old name: DEVPC
- New, correct name: DEVPC\SQLEXPRESS

Worked like a charm after that.

Comment: I had a similar experience, although I did not need to open any ports or add firewall exclusions, which is one of the points of the gateway. I was using `localhost\ServerName`, which did not work, but `MachineName\ServerName` worked.